# python pyodbc pass parameters issue

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pyodbc

Code:

```
import pyodbc as pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(DB_STR)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

def insert_table(insert_query,date_para):
    result = cursor.execute(insert_query,date_para)
    cnxn.commit()
```

The code is used to pass a parameter in sql.

My issue is ,when there is no parameter need to be pass in sql,I still want to reuse insert_table function:

```
my_query ='''

insert into mytable ...
'''

insert_table(my_query,'')
```

If I leave the second parameter position empty or add something else there,I will get an error.

How should I modify the code ,so that it can work on both scenarios ,has parameter and has not parameter need to be pass?

Comment: How is an INSERT going to work if there is nothing to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I leave the second parameter position empty or add something else there,I will get an error.

An empty tuple is valid if the query has no parameters:

```py
import pyodbc

connection_string = (
    "DRIVER=PostgreSQL Unicode;"
    "SERVER=192.168.0.199;"
    "UID=scott;PWD=tiger;"
    "DATABASE=test;"
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("""\
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
id serial primary key, 
txt varchar(50) default '(unknown)')
""")

insert_query = "insert into tmp default values"
date_para = tuple()
crsr.execute(insert_query, date_para)
print(crsr.execute("select * from tmp").fetchall())
# [(1, '(unknown)')]
```